# Read HTML files directly from zip

Tags: html, wpf, zip

I'm attempting to build a custom help viewer app in WPF. I can ready HTML files directly from a zip archive (no unpacking), does anyone know if it's possible to somehow resolve (redirect) links to the css, images, and other anchor links?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [base element](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/base) to your pages to redirect relative links.

Another way would be to control the downloads, but I don't know if that is easy or even possible. You might search the [All-In-One Code Framework](http://1code.codeplex.com/) for a sample of that.

You might need to subscribe the navigation events to change them.